# Detect if Mumble is installed on the current computer

Tags: c#, .net

As the title says I am trying to figure out a way, my C# application can determine if Mumble is installed on the PC or not.

I checked the regular Registery places but could not find any one for UninstallString or something.

Does anyone know a reliable way to detect if Mumble is installed on the PC?

Comment: Can't you just ask the user?

Comment: I'm guessing this is for some automated process that either uses it directly, or has some sort of conflict with it...

Comment: Yeah I guess. The problem is that it's pretty unreliable. Maybe the user had Mumble installed but uninstalled it, and the uninstaller didn't delete the registry keys? Or the user had it installed but removed it by just deleting the Mumble-directory in C:\Programs. If it's possible you should ask the user, then it's the users fault if he or she answer incorrectly :-)

Comment: Well the reason I need this, is I am developing a small software for a star citizen community. And in that WPF application I have a button to start and connect to the mumble server. I would like to have that button greyed out when its not installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Mumble [adds some registry keys](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blob/master/installer/Files.wxs#L25) during installation.  Would that work?

Comment: Thanks. I noticed this Registery key, but what happens when I uninstall it? I also noticed it places the whole config (audio config, UI config, ...) in the registery. Are the regstgiery keys still there after uninstallation?

Comment: Tested this with the registry value in HK_ClassesRoot and seems to work :)